# .gitattributes on Windows modifies all files incorrectly

Tags: windows, git, gitattributes

I clone the repo, open it on IDE on Windows, and it shows to me, that I modified all the files. When I add them and push, it shows me in the pull request, that I have changed them from the beginning to the end, even though the content is the same and I didn't make any changes. Is there any way to solve the problem?

The .gitattributes file is the following:

```
*.js text eol=crlf
*.jsx text eol=crlf

bin/* eol=lf
```

My git configs on the computer are the following:

```
[user]
    name = ****
    email = ***
[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = true
[core]
    autocrlf = input
```

What I have tried:

1. I have tried the following commands ([a piece of advice from Krzysztof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64609616)):

   ```
   git rm --cached -r .
   git reset --hard
   ```
2. Set git config to `core.autocrlf input` (a piece of advice from a programmer-friend of a colleague)

   ```
   git config --global core.autocrlf input
   ```
3. Delete the repo and clone it again several times

Comment: It's not normal to have `bin/* eol=lf`; it's much more normal to have `bin/* binary`. But: if you *change* the `eol=` setting for various source files, you must usually *re-add* those files with `git add --renormalize`, and then commit (with a commit message along the lines of "renormalize text files - no actual changes, please skip this commit"). You *will* change all the changed files, and *you* will own this commit, but it must be done because the previous versions of the committed files are now wrong.

Comment: Since *no existing commit can ever be changed at all*, you must make a new commit that corrects previous errors, adding that to the repository. You own this correction. If you later wish to skip the commit during a `git bisect`, for instance, you simply tell Git "skip this commit". The commit still needs to *exist* though. The same holds for `git blame` (though here you need to tell `git blame` to skip the revision *before* you run it).